# Unable to update item in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android i have made a project to store members information in one activity and in another activity i display members in listView and on onlong clicking listview i open another activity to update members information but when i click on update button it adds that record instead of Updating.

My Firebase Structure :

[image]

My activity for storing :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText txtname,txtage,txtheight,txtphone;
 Button btnsave,btnRead;
  Member member;
 DatabaseReference reff;
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtname = findViewById(R.id.txtname);
    txtage =findViewById(R.id.txtage);
    txtphone =findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
    txtheight =findViewById(R.id.txtheight);
    btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    btnRead =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
    btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActivity();
        }
        private void openActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Retreivedata.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    member = new Member();
    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");

    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddUsers();
        }
    });
    }

private void AddUsers(){
    String name = txtname.getText().toString().trim();
    String age = txtage.getText().toString().trim();
    String phone = txtphone.getText().toString().trim();
    String ht = txtheight.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        String id =  reff.push().getKey();
        Member member = new Member(id, name, age, phone, ht);
        reff.child(id).setValue(member);
        Toast.makeText(this,"User Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txtheight.setText("");
        txtphone.setText("");
        txtage.setText("");
        txtname.setText("");
    }else {
        txtname.setError("Enter Name");
    }
} 
}
```

My activity for displaying records in listview:

```
  public class Retreivedata extends AppCompatActivity {
  ListView listView;
   FirebaseDatabase database;
   DatabaseReference ref;
  ArrayList<Member> list;
  ArrayAdapter<Member> adapter;
  Member member;
 Button btnDlt;
 Boolean a=false;
 String val="";
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retreivedata);
    member = new Member();
   listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnDlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDlt);
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   ref = database.getReference("Member");
   list = new ArrayList<>();
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Member>(this,R.layout.list_white_text,R.id.userInfo, list);
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for(DataSnapshot dts: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                     {
                         member = dts.getValue(Member.class);
                         list.add(member);
           }
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });

      btnDlt.setEnabled(false);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Boolean a=true;
          Member member=adapter.getItem(position);
          Toast.makeText(Retreivedata.this,"Do u want to delete this record!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if (a==true)
          {
              btnDlt.setEnabled(true);

          }else{
              btnDlt.setEnabled(false);
          }
      }
  });

  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Member member= adapter.getItem(position);
          Intent intent = new Intent(Retreivedata.this, Update.class);
          intent.putExtra("tem", member);
          startActivity(intent);
          return false;
      }
  });

    btnDlt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                ref.child(member.getMemberId()).removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(Retreivedata.this, "Record deleted Successfully", 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter.remove(member);
                adapter.clear();

        }
    });

}
}
```

My activity for updating record:

```
 public class Update extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText EditTxtName,EditTxtAge,txtPhone,txtHeight;
Member member;
FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference reff;
Button btnUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    EditTxtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxtName);
    EditTxtAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxtAge);
    txtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    txtHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
    btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    final Member member= (Member) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tem");

    EditTxtName.setText(member.getName());
    EditTxtAge.setText(member.getAge());
    txtPhone.setText(member.getPhone());
    txtHeight.setText(member.getHeight());

    reff = db.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Update();
        }
    });


 }
 private void Update(){
    final String mnam = EditTxtName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String mage = EditTxtAge.getText().toString().trim();
     final String mph = txtPhone.getText().toString().trim();
     final String mhei = txtHeight.getText().toString().trim();
       final String ID =  reff.getKey();
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mnam)) {
       EditTxtName.setText("Plz enter name");}
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mage)) {
    EditTxtName.setText("Plz enter age");}
else{
 final Member member = new Member(ID,mnam,mage,mph,mhei);
         reff.child("Member").child(ID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
               reff.child("Member").child(ID).child("name").setValue(mnam);

             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });
            Toast.makeText(Update.this,"Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtHeight.setText("");
    txtPhone.setText("");
  EditTxtName.setText("");
  }
   }
}
```

But after updating record it creates another record.Suggest me what changes has to be done on update button click.

Thnaks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First I assume that you implement Serializable for your `Member` class:**

```
class Member implements Serializable{
.............
.............
.............

}
```

**Since you are passing the member object to the `update` activity, why not use the ID in it to update the data:**

```
//the update activity
public class Update extends AppCompatActivity {

//this is the member that you pass
Member member;

......
......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.........
.........
//this is how you retrieve it
member= (Member) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tem");

//this is your ref
reff = db.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");

........
........

}

//when you update

private void Update(){

final String mnam = EditTxtName.getText().toString().trim();
final String mage = EditTxtAge.getText().toString().trim();
final String mph = txtPhone.getText().toString().trim();
final String mhei = txtHeight.getText().toString().trim();

//update the name field
reff.child(member.getMemberId()).child("name").setValue(mnam);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line of code `final String ID =  reff.getKey()`
That call generates a new ID which you then use in your update of the db. You need to replace the call to getKey with the ID of the member you want to update.